# how to modify the wordpress main loop?

Tags: wordpress-theming, wordpress

i have a single page website built on wordpress (twenty-thirteen-child template).
header content footer.
and 3 posts categories :category A category B category C.
i need to split the content into these 3 categories/sections -like this

```
<div class="section_top">
  all the posts from category A
</div>
<div class="section_mid">
  all the posts from category B
</div>
<div class="section_bot">
  all the posts from category C
</div>
```

i got a little confused when i started to read about the wordpress main loop ,query_posts and WP_Query,eventually i have this code replacing the main loop ,so my questions are :

1 is this the correct way to do it?

2 how to give each section a unique class since i need to style each section diffrently?

here is the code (index php(in child theme)

```
        <div id="primary" class="content-area">

    <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main"> 

<?php

$args = array('category__in' => array(catA,catB,catC));
$category_posts = new WP_Query($args);
if($category_posts->have_posts()) : 
  while($category_posts->have_posts()) : 

     $category_posts->the_post();

?>

  <div id="<?php
  foreach((get_the_category()) as $category) {echo $category->cat_name . ' ';}?>"
     class="post-item">
              <div class="post-info">
        <h2 class="post-title">
        <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
        </h2>
      </div>
      <div class="post-content">
      <?php the_content(); ?>
      </div>
    </div>


<?php
  endwhile;
else: 
?>
  Oops, there are no posts.
<?php
endif;
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with how you're trying to solve it is that all posts are still shown chronologically, so this could happen:

```
Category A post 12/01
Category B post 09/01
Category A post 05/01
```

What I'd recommend: make 3 different WordPress loops querying each category separately like so:

```
<div class="section_top">
   WordPress loop for all the posts from category A
</div>
<div class="section_mid">
  WordPress loop for all the posts from category B
</div>
<div class="section_bot">
  WordPress loop for all the posts from category C
</div>
```

Example of such a loop:

```
// The Query
$the_query = new WP_Query('category_name=categoryA');

// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        echo '<ul>';
    while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
        $the_query->the_post();
        echo '<li>' . get_the_title() . '</li>';
    }
        echo '</ul>';
} else {
    // no posts found
}
/* Restore original Post Data */
wp_reset_postdata();
```

**Difference between get_the_...() and the_...()**

When you use functions like `get_the_title()` you are able to store them in a PHP variable like so:

```
$title = get_the_title();
echo strtoupper($title); //do something with it later
```

When you use functions like `the_title()` then the title is immediately printed on the page, so there's no need for an echo statement:

```
the_title();
```

*Notice: `the_permalink()` has a function `get_permalink()`, the function `get_the_permalink()` does not exist. Don't ask my why ;)*

Comment: excellent thank you very much 1.are there any cons or problems using many loops instead of one? 2.inside the loop is it get_ the_title or just the title? 3. if i want to add the content of the post is it something like this: echo '<li>';
        echo the_title() ;
        echo the_content(); ;
        echo '</li>';.again thank you.

Comment: There are no problems using multiple loops, this is even in de codex: http://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop#Multiple_Loops || Edited the post with more information about functions which you can use in the loop, don't forget to upvote ;)

Comment: Is there a way to put this code at an external widget or something, and just override the loop? editing this directing in the theme would make me lost the change when the theme is uodated.

Comment: also, instead hardcoding each category, I could, for instance, iterate over a list of categories ans inside this loop, run the loop described above, as a inner loop?